# Method for storing data for 300 entry lookup table (c#)

Tags: c#, web-config, encapsulation, appsettings, lookup-tables

I'm currently extending some existing code that utilizes a lookup table.  As it is now the table is about 25 entries and, for better or worse,  the key/values are stored in the appsettings section of the web.conf.  They are read into a dictionary and used throughout the application.

I'll be increasing the size of the lookup table to around 300 entries, which is the complete set of values for this domain - so it's not likely that it will get much larger nor change frequently.  I'm not sure that keeping this data in the web.conf is a good idea.   A database is not an option for this implementation, so i'm looking for a alternative way to store this data .  Some of my thoughts are:

- A static dictionary?
- Xml file (or some other flat external datafile)
- Leaving it in the appsettings section of web.conf?

I'm leaning toward populating a static dictionary in a class that will contain methods for manipulating the dataset.  Any advice, comments or cries of outrage would be appreciated.

Comment: Xml file (or some other flat external datafile) gets my vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store your additional key value pairs in a config file referenced via the appSettings element - this keeps your main config file neat, and stores the additional config in it's own dependent config file.

This is explained in the article [MSDN - appSettings Element (General Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This is effectively a combination of your second and third items.

I wouldn't put it in a static dictionary inside the code for maintenance reasons - a config file is a more obvious place for this data too. By leveraging the built in .Net functionality, you also don't run the risk of someone else ignoring the Xml file for example.

A more concrete example would be (note file paths are relative to the main application):

**app.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>   

   <appSettings file="mykeyvaluepairs.config"/>

</configuration>
```

**mykeyvaluepairs.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>

  <add key="imaginativelynamedkey1" value="imaginativelynamedvalue1" />

</appSettings>
```

Note that in your original app.config, it is also okay to do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>   

   <appSettings file="mykeyvaluepairs.config">
       <add key="CanBeOverridenByItemInChildConfigFileWithSameName" value="UnicornsGoHere" />
   </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

That is, unless you redefine the appsettings in the mykeyvaluepairs.config file, both will exist side by side - but items with the same name in mykeyvaluepairs.config will override values in the main config.

Comment: Thanks dash, this method fits well into our project. I went with the configSource attribute so I could define custom external sections.

Comment: The MSDN link is broken. If, instead of "MSDN" you had used the target page title, I might have been able to Google the link, and edit the post for you.

Comment: @Faust - thanks for spotting this. I have updated the link to point at the correct resource (and will try and remember to use the page title in future :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for encapsulation the best way would be to expose an interface that will return the value you want and then inject concrete implementation. Thanks to this you may then easily change the implementation.

When it goes to implementation, if data never changes or changes are for next release (basically, if only developer can make changes) I would go for underlying dictionary (and configure it as a Singleton in DI Container). What is more, I would keep keys as enum values that would give additional type safety. IMHO if something is not configurable by administrators or business users keeping it in external configuration only adds unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Xml file example for you.  You leverage it like:

```
string value = MyConfig.Items[key];
```

To add new values to it:

```
MyConfig.Write(file => file.Add("newKey", "newValue"));
```

The class:

```
public class MyConfig : IDisposable
{
    string file = "path to file";  // probably in App_Data if this is asp.net
    XElement self;

    public MyConfig()
    {
        if(File.Exists(file))
            self = XElement.Load(file);
        else
            self = new XElement("root");
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        if (!Items.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            self.Add(new XElement("pair",
                new XAttribute("Key", key),
                new XAttribute("Value", value)));
            _Items = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        self.Save(file);
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _Items)
            {
                _Items = Read.self.Elements().ToDictionary(
                    x => x.Attribute("Key").Value,
                    x => x.Attribute("Value").Value);
            }
            return _Items;
        }
    }
    static Dictionary<string, string> _Items;

    public static MyConfig Read { get { return new MyConfig(); } }
    public static void Write(Action<MyConfig> action)
    {
        using (MyConfig config = new MyConfig())
            action(config);
    }
}
```

You may want to lock the _Items variable when assigning/reading to/from it, since websites are multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` is a good choice for handling key/value information in your code. It's better to keep your config file lean and mean so do not put all your 300 keys and values there. You can use XML serialization to easily store (and load) bulky or numerous custom settings in a separate XML file. Seems like a good match for you case.

Use this example code to save/load data to/from an XML.

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;
}

static void Save()
{
    // some test data
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("key1", "value1");
    dict.Add("key2", "value2");
    dict.Add("key3", "value3");
    dict.Add("key4", "value4");

    // convert to List
    List<KeyValue> list1 = (from itm in dict
                            select new KeyValue
                                       {
                                           Key = itm.Key, Value = itm.Value
                                       }).ToList();

    // serialize
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\config.xml"))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<KeyValue>));
        xs.Serialize(sw, list1);
        sw.Close();
    }
}

static void Load()
{
    // deserialize
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\config.xml"))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<KeyValue>));
        List<KeyValue> list2 = (List<KeyValue>) xs.Deserialize(sr);
        sr.Close();
    }

    // convert to Dictionary
    Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = list2.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

*Note: You need `KeyValue` helper class because the result of `dict.ToList()` which is `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` does not serialize properly.*